# React Router: wildcard matching matches other routes with query parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Using React Router v5. I've got a bunch of routes like the following and a wildcard path Route at the very end:

```js
<Router>
<Switch>

<Route path="/" exact><Component /></Route>
<Route path="/1" exact><Component1 /></Route>
<Route path="/1/blah" exact><Component2 /></Route>
<Route path="/3" exact><Component3 /></Route>
<Route path="*">
    <Redirect to="/" />
</Route>

</Switch>
</Router>
```

I'm trying to go to `/1?query=123` but then I get redirected back to `/`. If I remove the wildcard Route, then going to `/1?query=123` goes to its specified component. The point of the wildcard is to match if the path is completely unknown. How would I do that?

Edit: for further context (never thought it was necessary), but I have an odd file structure.

It looks like: file 1 `<BrowserRouter><AllRoutes /></etc.>` then in file 2: `<Switch><Route /><Route /><MoreRoutes></Switch>` then in file 3: `<><Route /><Route /><Route path="*" /></>` where file 3 is the code above.

Edit 2: apparently doing some inclusion stuff with MoreRoutes in file 2 was causing the issue. How to actually include the "MoreRoutes" variable is something I haven't figured out yet. Because if you put the Redirect wildcard Route after the `<MoreRoutes />` or `{MoreRoutes}`, the wildcard isn't matched anymore

Comment: I can't reprodce this, it [works fine for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/rrd-wildcard-with-query-demo-gq0mf). On a broader note, `<Route path="*">` is mostly redundant in a `Switch`, because if you get to the end and you haven't had a match, then you are on an unknown/unexpected path. I would just get rid of it.

Comment: @lawrence-witt thanks for the explanation and quick demo! Unfortunately for me, removing Switch still doesn't work as everything immediately matches to the wildcard. I'll update the question with more context, but in other words, I use several files. So it looks like: file 1 `<BrowserRouter><AllRoutes /></etc.>` then in file 2: `<Switch><Route /><Route /><MoreRoutes></Switch>` then in file 3: `<><Route /><Route /><Route path="*" /></>` where file 3 is the code from the question.

Comment: I didn't mean get rid of the switch, I meant get rid of the wildcard route and just have the `Redirect` there by itself.

Comment: I think your issue is probably not related to this file and more so the whole folder structure and imported routes. All the descendents of a `Switch` must be `Route` or `Redirect`. I vaguely recall that it will not function correctly when you import routes wrapped in another component.

Comment: Gotcha. So I tried just using the Redirect without the wildcard and the results were the same as the initial. Perhaps instead of making it a component, just use it as a function: `<Switch>{MoreRoutes()}</Switch>`? where MoreRoutes == `<><Route />etc.</>`? Or should `<>` be `<Route>`?

Comment: Ah ok so the problem was doing some inclusion with components and even doing `{VARIABLE}` isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "exact" from the path.

```
<Router>
<Switch>

<Route path="/"><Component /></Route>
<Route path="/1"><Component1 /></Route>
<Route path="/2"><Component2 /></Route>
<Route path="/3"><Component3 /></Route>
<Route path="*">
    <Redirect to="/" />
</Route>

</Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Same result. I guess I should also note that /1 and /2 are actually `/1` and `/1/blah`. Question updated.

Comment: Could you not include it as a path parameter instead?
<Route path="/users/:id" component={UserPage}/>

Comment: The /1/blah parameter? No. Is there a reason query parameters don't match when used with exact?

Comment: Yea, because they are part of the path, which means it is not an exact match.

Comment: Gotcha. So perhaps instead of `<Route exact path="/1">` etc., is an inline wildcard possible? `<Route path ="/1?*">`? Also, according to the docs, `exact` is for pathname, which doesn't include query params.

Comment: You can keep exact on "/" or else it will always match with that one first. Either that, or move it to just above the wildcard route.

Comment: Query parameters are not part of the path. Making it exact/not-exact will have no effect.